# shardcollection with existing document mongodb

Tags: mongodb, sharding

Let's say that I had a collection called "History" and "Employees" and there will a document on it.

When I create first collection with

```
sh.shardCollection("Databases.History",{"email":1})
```

it works fine, and I add some document on it.

But. When I create the second collections named "Employees" with

```
db.Employees.insert({"name":"Jhon Wick", "email":"jw@goodemail.com"})
```

and create a shard collections on it with

```
sh.shardCollection("Databases.Employees",{"email":1})
```

, it doesn't work.

MongoDB says that "**please create an index that starts with the shard key before sharding.**"

so I tried add some index to Employees with `db.Employees.ensureIndex({"email":"hashed"})`
and it works. But when I tried `shardCollection` again, it still return that error.

What should I do?

Do MongoDB have a rules that if I would add shardKeys on a collection, it (collection) must not exist at first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your index strategy must be same as yout shard strategy. If you have created a hashed index, then you must specify hashed strategy while sharding.

`sh.shardCollection("Databases.Employees",{"email":1})`

shoule be replace with

`sh.shardCollection("Databases.Employees",{"email":"hashed"})`

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/shard-collection-with-a-hashed-shard-key/#shard-the-collection

Comment: Omg, that's what I'm missing. I don't read the docs clearly. Apologize. Would you kindly explain the different from 2 ways that I do?

Anyway, it's help me to solve my problem. Thank you very much